# Elasticsearch: Custom Token Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-6.8

Since there is no documentation about the subject, it is very complicated to understand how to implement a custom token filter plugin from scratch in Java.

I'd like to get an analyzer filter that returns only tokens that are numbers for example.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are existing filters that do this. For instance the [`keep_types` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keep-types-tokenfilter.html#analysis-keep-types-tokenfilter-analyze-include-ex) can do exactly that.

If you leverage the `<NUM>` type, your custom token filter is going to only let numeric tokens through and filter out all others.

```
GET _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "keep_types",
      "types": [ "<NUM>" ]
    }
  ],
  "text": "1 quick fox 2 lazy dogs"
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 2]
```

You can achieve a similar result with the [`pattern_capture` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) as well.

But if you really want to go the Java way, then you're best best is to clone an [existing analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins) and roll your own.

Comment: Hi Val, thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm not really looking for a solution using existing filters. I need to implement a filter plugin from scratch using Java class.

Comment: Then, you're best best is to clone an [existing analysis plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins) and roll your own.